# Movement start/end point detection

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, gesture-recognition

I'm now working with Kinect in my project of worker-support. 
I want to use Kinect to detect start/end moment of a specified movement in work-process.
For example:
A work-process of drawing circle into papers (on a table) have some steps: (a tester) pick-up pen from table, **draw circle**, put-back pen on table, change the paper,...(repeat many times).
And i want detect the **moments** when the tester **start** and **finish** drawing circle.
I have to propose an **high-accuracy** algorithm that non-depends on **position** and **size** of tester.
Can you give me some idea!
Thanks for help (and sorry about my English)!

Comment: Are you using Opensource or the SDK? What language? Please be more specific

Comment: one tip : for the algorithm to be not depend on the position and the tester, don't use the actual co-ordinates in your algorithm.Instead use the distance from a reference point(take hip).You know almost all the human have the same body propotion [see Vitruvian_man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitruvian_man).

Comment: @Outlaw Lemur: I'm using Microsoft Kinect for Windows SDK v1.5 and C#.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give you some ideas?
http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Open-source-Kinect-gesture-recognition-project-Kinect-DTW

Comment: Thanks for helps!
These are some changes in my project purpose, but DTW is a good idea for me,I think.